# How to demonstrate that the average value of sinusoidal functions is zero?

Tags: average

I've been directed here from the Electronic engineering website, since it's more of a math question. I need to demonstrate that given in the title, given this formula:

[image]

I know I have to replace i(t) with sin(t). But what interval should I choose for this integral? Should it be [0,1] as this is the interval that sin is defined in?

Comment: Is $T$ the period with $i(t+T)=i(t)$? If so, integrating from $t_1$ to $t_1+T$ makes sense.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I get your point :(

Answer (score 1):

What you can show using that formula is that the average value of a sinusoidal function **over its period** is zero. Assuming that you know the basics of integral calculus, and taking into account that $t_1$ in that formula is arbitrary (so can be chosen equal to zero) you can simply evaluate this term:

$$\int_0^Ti(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi}sin(t)dt = 0$$

where T is the period of a sinusoidal function.

So, dividing this result by $2\pi$, that is the period you still get zero.

Hope this helps.

D.